# How to write temporary files to /tmp using Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create/retrieve temporary files in a directory named /tmp

Based on: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-temp-files

However I am seeing an error saying this is a **read-only file system** (as below):

[image]

I created a tmp directory myself (as below). Is it possible the tmp directory I should be accessing is located elsewhere?

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: For more context, I deployed a flask app using the standard app engine. I understand there are better storage options. As my app is simple, I wanted to get away with leveraging the temp directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking your picture it seems you are trying to write into `./tmp` instead of `/tmp` is this right?

Comment: Does that not directly conflict with the official documentation? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-temp-files

Comment: In fact, after some research this answer is deprecated, I will look for something else

Comment: I appreciate it. I've spent a month trying to fix it but still no luck...

Comment: I modified the answer, am I right?

Comment: That is true. I am using ./tmp instead of /tmp. Why would that make any difference though? Will give it a shot.

Comment: It is totally different, because "." Represent the current working directory. So when you begin your path by "." That means "in the current directory, in the folder "tmp" in it,....." Whereas "/" represente the root of the system. Since the system is read only everywhere else other that "/tmp", ./tmp is then read-only. For example if the working directory is "/home" then in your configuration your are trying to create a file into "/home/tmp/..."

Comment: I am seeing a different error now: " FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/uploads/example.mp3' " Do you think it could be because I'm trying to access a directory "/uploads" within tmp?

Comment: Ok great, the main right error is fixed !! Now this error comes either because the folder /tmp/uploads/ does not exists or beacause the file /tmp/uploads/example.mp3 - create them if needed and make sure to use /tmp instead of ./tmp :)

Comment: thanks! Will keep working from there and have you posted.